# Java - How to get the account names and check is any of them are similar

Tags: java

I am working on [this](http://www.hpcodewars.org/past/cw2/problems/PROB07.HTM) for a programming class and I can't seem to think of a way to get past this one part of the problem. I've tried some things but nothing has worked so I figured I'll ask here and see what people say. The problem I am having is that I can't think of a way to get the names of the account holder and compare it to said names to check if there are any duplicates. After that I believe I can finish the problem.

My Code as of now

```
    //Account Balancing - 5 Points

    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Account {
                public static void main(String[] args){
            //File Variables
            String inputFile = "AccountInput.txt";
            String outputFile = "AccountOutput.txt";
            Scanner Document = null;
            PrintWriter NewFile = null;

            try {
                Document = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));
                NewFile = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true));
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Could not find " + inputFile);
                System.exit(0);
                System.out.println("Could not find " + outputFile);
                System.exit(0);
            }

            while(Document.hasNextLine()){
                String line = Document.nextLine();
                String[] pieces = line.split(" ");
                //System.out.println(pieces[0]);
                //System.out.println(pieces[1]);
                //System.out.println(pieces[2]);

                //if statement that checks to see if second word in line is "BALANCE" then checks the first word (name) and sees if the account is new or not
                if (pieces[1].equals("BALANCE")){
                    for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
                        System.out.println(pieces[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This block makes no sense by the way: `catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Could not find " + inputFile);
                System.exit(0);
                System.out.println("Could not find " + outputFile);
                System.exit(0);
            }`

Comment: You need to have class variables in your Account class and methods to set and get them. This way you will have "storage" for each individual account.  Then you will need to place these objects into `Collection` (`ArrayList` or whatever) and program your logic accordingly.

Comment: But beyond that block of code, the code you've got doesn't even begin to solve much of what the `Homework` asks of you.  You need to make an effort to solve an issue and post back here when you've got a specific problem with a specific part of your `Homework`.  No one is going to do your homework for you, but we will help when you get stuck as long as you can demonstrate that you've got an idea of how to do it.  If you're looking for a way to compare `String`s in Java, look at the documentation, look at the `equals` method.

Comment: It seems that *first deposit* should create an Account object.

Answer (score 0):

names of account holder is first word in each line of input?
create a hash map
trawl through the file and add the name to the hashmap if it's not present.
then you can use that to mine the output an find all the messges for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific as to what the problem is. Is it that you require to read the files and get the names of the account holder from the files and then compare them to user input or you have already got the account holder names in a collection and cant figure to what to do next.
If your case is the later one then you can use a vector and use .contains("value") method to find the required name

Comment: `Vector` has synchronization semantics that are almost certainly not wanted here, and its `contains` method is O(n) whereas the `contains` method of a `Map` or `Set` is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

You say you can't think of any way to get the names of the account holder, but you are already splitting the input lines on spaces. If you only wanted to detect duplicate account holders, a `Set<String>` could tell you which names you've already seen. However, since you'll need to look up accounts by name, you might as well keep them in a `Map<String, BigDecimal>` which would map the account holder to their balance.

Do not use a floating point format such as `double` or `float` for the balance, since floating point should never be used for money. I would use a `BigDecimal` with a scale of two, but you could also use a `long` or `BigInteger` and store the balance as a whole number of cents. If you do use `BigDecimal`, beware of the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor, which has surprisingly bad semantics. If you never have the amount in any floating point format, even temporarily, you'll be fine.